# Which forms of a noun do I have to memorise when learning Koine Greek?

Tags: koine-greek

I recently began learning from Mounce's Basics of Biblical Greek. He says you should learn the lexical form, stem and article of a noun. Can these things not be worked out if you just learn the lexical form?

I want to start memorising the vocabulary as I mean to go on, so my question is which forms of the noun do I have to learn to be able to read and translate from Koine Greek?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As Mounce said, it's important to learn the articles of all the nouns because it's not always obvious what they should be from just the lexical form. A good example of that is ἡ ἔρημος (the desert, wilderness) which is a second declension noun. Most second declension nouns are masculine and have ὁ for the article, but ἡ ἔρημος is feminine and takes the feminine article.

It's also important to learn the stem of all the nouns because the lexical form isn't always a good indication of what it should be. For example, ἡ νύξ (the night) has for its stem νύκτ-, which isn't obvious. Another example is ὁ πατήρ, which might lead you to think that the stem would be πατ-, when actually it's πατρ-.

One good way to learn the stem is to learn the genitive singular and drop the ending. For example, the genitive singular of πατήρ is πατρός. By dropping the ending -ός, you get the stem πατρ-.

Comment: Ah thanks, this explains how the grammar is listed without the stem in Mounce's book.

Answer (score 6):

The stem can't always be derived from the lexical form. For example, in the third declension, the nominative singular (i.e. the lexical form) is usually formed by adding an *-s*, which often obscures the end of the stem:

- *glau**c**-s* > *glaux*, *ony**ch**-s* > *onyx*, *ptery**g**-s* > *pteryx*
- *tapē**t**-s* > *tapēs*, *Tyrin**th**-s* > *Tyrins*, *po**d**-s* > *pous*
- *clō**p**-s* > *clōps*, *katēli**ph**-s* > *katēlips*, *Ara**b**-s* > *Araps*

And, unfortunately, the lexical form can't always be derived from the stem either. This often goes back to something called Proto-Indo-European ablaut, and doesn't follow any regular pattern in Greek; it just has to be memorized.

- Stem *patr-*, but lexical form *patēr*
- Stem *geront-*, but lexical form *gerōn*
- Stem *rhētor-*, but lexical form *rhētōr*

So you need to memorize both. Similarly, the gender isn't always predictable from the form—there's no good way to know which of the nouns I just listed are masculine vs feminine without memorizing each one—so you'll need to learn that too.